# access to properties of an array contain json formatted elements in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

suppose I have an Array like this :

```
$myArray =
[
    {
        "id": 86,
        "name": "admin/login"
    },
    {
        "id": 87,
        "name": "admin/logout"
    },
    {
        "id": 88,
        "name": "admin/desktop"
    }
]
```

Each element of array has json format. and now I want to get `name` of element that have `id` of `87` for example.

Firstly How can I found that is there element with this id then get `name` property of that?

Comment: Is this a multidimensional array? Or a string? ...?

Comment: this is like what you see exactly.no more. an array of json elements only.

Comment: Then this is a hill of errors: https://3v4l.org/2rlpu

Comment: I edit post to right json format.

Comment: Same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543869/access-to-properties-of-an-array-contain-json-formatted-elements-in-laravel#comment60688925_36543869

Comment: see at : http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb10c27b, that has not error

Comment: So you have a json string here and NOT an array?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108798/discussion-between-a-b-developer-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode JSON string into array. Then use Laravel's [array_first](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-first) method.

```
<?php
$myArray = '[{"id": 86,"name": "admin/login"},{"id": 87,"name": "admin/logout"},{"id": 88,"name": "admin/desktop"}]';

// Decode into array
$array = json_decode($myArray, true);

// Find item with correct id
$result = array_first($array, function($key, $value){
  return $value['id'] === 87;
}, false);

if ($result) {
    echo 'Item found, it\'s name is: '.$result['name'];
}
```

If you have `id` you like to find in variable, you have to use `use` construct.

```
// ID to search for
$searchID = 87;

// Find item with correct id
$result = array_first($array, function($key, $value) use($searchID){
  return $value['id'] === $searchID;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

$newArray = json_decode($myArray);

and you'll get type of array

```
[
    [
        "id"=> 86,
        "name"=> "admin/login"
    ],.....
    ........
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $myArray is incorrect so, assuming it is a json string you can do this in the following way :

1. At first json_decode it into an arry.
2. Loop through the elements to find out you desired value(87).
3. Keep a flag which will tell if you have actually found any value.

   ```
   <?php

   $myArray =
   '[
       {
           "id": 86,
           "name": "admin/login"
       },
       {
           "id": 87,
           "name": "admin/logout"
       },
       {
           "id": 88,
           "name": "admin/desktop"
       }
   ]';

   $myArray = json_decode($myArray , true);

   $found = 0;

   foreach($myArray as $anArray)


   {

       if($anArray['id'] == 87)
       {
            var_dump($anArray['name']);
            $found = 1;
       }
   }

   if($found == 1)
   {
        var_dump("Element found.");
   }
   else
   {
        var_dump("Element not found. ");
   }

   ?>
   ```